# Making a push notification alert more aggressive

Tags: iphone, notifications, apple-watch, apns

Is it possible to change how a push notification behaves when it's received on an iOS device and/or Apple Watch?

I ask because I have a diabetes tracking app for my step-daughter that only sends one notification, which results in just one vibration on my phone or watch.  I'd like to make that vibration happen several times, kinda like receiving a phone call so it's less likely we will miss the notification.

Are there any settings, affordances or apps that might help with this?

Comment: I've opened this up to settings and services. Of course, the app developer is the primary avenue to get repeat notifications or have some sort of "acknowledgment" but let's see what people have in mind to help.

Comment: Thanks!  I have contacted the company directly too,  but wanted to check the Apple commmnity too